# Strange mv -vf output under en_US.UTF-8

Tags: linux, ubuntu, language

My `mv -vf` output is very strange:

```
cd /tmp
touch xx yy

$ mv -vf xx yy
â -> â

$ env | grep ^LANG
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

The correct output should be:

```
$ mv -vf xx yy
'xx' -> 'yy'
```

This is from,

```
$ env | grep ^LANG
LANG=C
```

If I set `LANG=C` then the `mv -vf` output is correct again.

**Update** on checking `locale -a`:

```
$ locale -a | grep en
en_US
en_US.utf8

LANG=en_US.utf8

touch xx yy

$ mv -vf xx yy
â -> â

LANG=en_US
touch xx yy

$ mv -vf xx yy
'xx' -> 'yy'
```

How is that? Would there be any fix?

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:        15.04
Codename:       vivid
```

BTW, just test the same thing under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial, and the problem is gone, despite my `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. So it is a bug of Ubuntu 15.04 then? I've got several machines using Ubuntu 15.04 and they all exhibit the same behavior. Does that occur to you at all?

**Update 2**:

```
$ locale -a | grep ^C
C
C.UTF-8

LANG=C.UTF-8
touch xx yy

$ mv -vf xx yy
â -> â
```

So it has nothing to do with `en` but `UTF-8` under Ubuntu 15.04 actually (as setting `LANG=C` works).

Comment: Please check with `locale -a` that the desired locale is actually available.

Comment: @DanielB, checked and updated my OP. Thx.

Comment: Okay, that points to an issue with the terminal you're using. Which terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: @DanielB, xterm and urxvt, both have the same symptom.

Answer (score -1):

Please examine the `/etc/default/locale` file and set your desired `LANG`.  Try relogon or logon with another user to see if it is working.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Please explain how this helps answer the question. Because I think it doesn’t.